# Menu de opciones en BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script

Tengo un script hecho en bash, que tiene un menu de 11 opciones, y al elegir la opción 10, 11 no me funcionan porque me reconoce la opción 1.

```
********************************
1.-    Añadir Descripcion.
2.-    MINAGE - Linux
3.-    MAXAGE - Linux
4.-    Listar CUENTAS - Linux
5.-    MINAGE - Aix
6.-    MAXAGE - Aix
7.-    Listar CUENTAS de MINAGE- Aix
8.-    Listar CUENTAS de MAXAGE- Aix
9.-    MINLEN Sistemas Aix
10.-       LIstar MINLEN Sistemas Aix
11.-       Salir    
********************************

Seleccione una opcion de 1 a 11 ? :
```

El elegir opcion 1, me muestra : "Copia y Pega las DESCRIPCIONES, en el fichero descripciones.txt !"

Al elegir opcion 10 y 11, me muestra lo mismo : "Copia y Pega las DESCRIPCIONES, en el fichero descripciones.txt !", porque no me reconoce el 10 ni el 11.

Os muestro el código, esta reducido.

```
#!/bin/bash
# VARIABLES
miLista=(
    'Añadir Descripcion.'
    "MINAGE - Linux"
    'MAXAGE - Linux'
    'Listar CUENTAS - Linux'
    'MINAGE - Aix'
    'MAXAGE - Aix'
    'Listar CUENTAS de MINAGE- Aix'
    'Listar CUENTAS de MAXAGE- Aix'
    'MINLEN Sistemas Aix'
    'LIstar MINLEN Sistemas Aix'
    'Salir'
)
user=$(logname)
home="/home/${user}/Compliance/"

function descripcion_delMenu() {
    index=0
    for item in "${miLista[@]}"; do
        ((index = index + 1))
        echo -e "$index.-\t   ${item}"
    done
}

function logWarn() {
    START='\033[01;33m'
    END='\033[00;00m'
    MESSAGE=${@:-""}
    echo -e "${START}${MESSAGE}${END}"
}

function logInfo() {
    START='\033[01;32m'
    END='\033[00;00m'
    MESSAGE=${@:-""}
    echo -e "${START}${MESSAGE}${END}"
}

function logError() {
    START='\033[01;31m'
    END='\033[00;00m'
    MESSAGE=${@:-""}
    echo -e "${START}${MESSAGE}${END}"
}

function log() {
    MESSAGE=${@:-""}
    echo -e "${MESSAGE}"
}
# FUNCION CONTINUAR CON EL SCRIPT
function continuar() {
    while true; do
        log ""
        read -p "Desea Continuar S/N? : " yn
        case $yn in
        [Ss]*)
            clear
            menu
            break
            ;;
        [Nn]*)
            logError "Finaliza la Ejecución. !"
            exit
            ;;
        *) logWarn "\nSeleccione Si o No." ;;
        esac
    done
}

function add () {
    rm -f ${home}'descripciones.txt'
    nohup gedit ${home}'descripciones.txt' </dev/null >nohup.out 2>nohup.err &
}

function command_sed () {
    sed -i 's/:ES//g' "${home}descripciones.txt"
    sed -i 's/:CZ//g' "${home}descripciones.txt"
    sed -i 's/:DE//g' "${home}descripciones.txt"
}


function minlen () {
    command_sed
    cat  ${home}'descripciones.txt' | awk '{print "chsec -f /etc/security/user -s "$2 " -a minlen=14"}'
    cat  ${home}'descripciones.txt' | awk '{print "chsec -f /etc/security/user -s "$2 " -a minlen=14"}' > ${home}'resultado.txt'
    gedit ${home}'resultado.txt'
}

function listar_minlen () {
    command_sed
    cat  ${home}'descripciones.txt' | awk '{print "chsec -f /etc/security/user -s "$2 " -a minlen"}'
    cat  ${home}'descripciones.txt' | awk '{print "chsec -f /etc/security/user -s "$2 " -a minlen"}' > ${home}'resultado.txt'
    gedit ${home}'resultado.txt'
}

# FUNCION MENU
function menu() {
    while true; do
        echo -e "\t********************************"
        descripcion_delMenu
        echo -e "\t********************************"
        log ""
        read -p "Seleccione una opcion de 1 a ${#miLista[@]} ? : " op
        case $op in
        [1]*)
            clear
            logInfo "Copia y Pega las DESCRIPCIONES, en el fichero descripciones.txt !\n"
            add
            menu
            #continuar
            break
            ;;
        
        [10]*)
            clear
            logInfo "LISTAR CUENTAS para MINLEN para Sistemas Aix !\n"
            listar_minlen
            log ""
            menu
            #continuar
            break
            ;;
        [${#miLista[@]}]*)
            logError "Gracias !Hasta pronto! \n\n"
            break
            ;;
        *) logWarn "\nSeleccione una Opción de 1 a ${#miLista[@]}.\n" ;;
        esac
    done
}
log ""
clear
menu
```

Como podría hacer que me reconozca el 10 y el 11, independientemente??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando seleccionas 10 u 11 te está tomando la primera opción porque, en la primera opción de tu `case` le estás diciendo que si el valor empieza por 1 use la primera opción.

Al poner `[1]*`, el asterisco está diciendo que tome cualquier valor que empiece por 1 (10, 11, 134...), por lo que deberías quitar los asteriscos de todas tus opciones para que tome los valores que tú quieres.

Y, por ejemplo, en la opción del 10, al ponerlo entre corchetes `[10]` le estás diciendo "cualquier valor que tenga 1 o 0", que no es lo que quieres (si pones la opción 0 verás que te lleva a esa opción). En verdad, lo que tú estás buscando es el valor literal 10, por lo que deberías ponerlo directamente.

En resumen, sería algo así:

```
     case $op in
        1)
            ...
            break
            ;;

        10)
            ...
            break
            ;;
        ${#miLista[@]})
            ...
            break
            ;;
        *) logWarn "\nSeleccione una Opción de 1 a ${#miLista[@]}.\n" ;;
     esac
```

Espero te pueda servir

Comment: Funciona genial, te lo agradezco mucho no lo había tenido en cuenta, ahora que me lo comentas lo tengo más claro gracias

Comment: Me alegro, de nada! 